# How to inject Microsoft.Extensions.Logging from .Net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a library built by .Net standard 2, which aims to support our .Net Core 2 project and legacy .Net framework project.

In this .Net standard 2 library, I choose to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging as my logger, according to this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Here is the question: Since DI part is in the referenced library (.Net Core or .Net framework), **How could I inject the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging from .Net framework project**?

If it is impossible to do that, how could I achieve the logger that could be used both by .Net framework and .Net core?

Much thanks for any help!

Comment: Voting to close since you've linked to the duplicate.  [Sharing logger between different .NET frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49411520/sharing-logger-between-different-net-frameworks)